# MDM conflicts with Keychain-Access

Tags: objective-c, keychain, mdm

I'm developing an application that uses the keychain to store login credentials.
To access the keychain I'm using the *UICKeyChainStore*-library to make it easier.

When I'm running it on a device everything is working perfectly, credentials are stored and read from the keychain.

The application has to be MDM-wrapped and thats where the problem starts. 
As soon as it's wrapped I can't read or write from/to the keychain anymore whatsoever.

I tracked it down to a **SecItemCopyMatching** call, which checks if the value is already stored. In the unwrapped case I get the status-code -25300 = noItemFound back which is good, as the keychain is empty at start.

However with the exactly same parameters in the wrapped case the return-code is -50 which is the **errSecParam** error, telling me that the dictionary I put into the method is invalid.

I tried turning parameters on / off or leaving them away, nothing changes. Always -50 error-code.

Has anyone of you maybe had to deal with this kind of issue in the past? I'm really running out of ideas here.

The dictionary looks like this:

- kSecAttrAccount = PasswordIdentifier
- kSecAttrGeneric = PasswordIdentifier
- kSecAttrSynchonizable = kSecAttrSynchronizableAny
- kSecAttrService = "MyAppIdentifier"
- kSecClass = kSecClassGenericPassword

Like I said, when I don't wrap it, these parameters are perfectly fine and accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it turns out that this actually was a bug from Citrix MDM. When wrapped, the method SecItemCopyMatching **DOES NOT WORK**. It just doesn't. As workaround we now use SecItemInsert and check if the return-code is "duplicateItem".